# Turn off automatic view resolution spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using the spring MVC template in IntelliJ to create a webservice to produce JSON from a rest call.

```
package com.planit.mvc;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class BasicRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/{name}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Person test(@PathVariable String name) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setAge(10);
        p.setFirstName(name);
        p.setLastName(name);
        return p;    
    }        
}
```

The servlet dispatcher XML is as follows:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.planit.mvc"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

So when I navigate to the URL it throws an error as it's trying to resolve a view based on the `{name}` param of the URL.

What is the correct way to achieve what I am looking, while still allowing for automatic view resolution?

EDIT: When I call the url such as:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/test/variable
```

So hitting the BasicRestController, with the method test due to the /test section of the url, followed by the PathVariable "variable" I get this error in tomcat:

HTTP Status 404 - /WEB-INF/views/rest/test/variable.jsp

So it looks like its trying to resolve the view variable.jsp which of course does not exist. I simply want it to give me back the JSON representation of the Person object, and not have to render it into a view.

Comment: Which view do you want to be rendered?

Comment: I just want it to display the json to the screen, so that when I use it from a client and call a url I can parse the json response. So there will be no view to resolve.

Comment: This works fine for me on Spring 4.0.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Looking at the spring docs, should RestController not have this by default?

Comment: @user1089599 Yes, you are absolutely correct. `@RestController` implicitly adds the `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: It still however is trying to resolve a view when I call the url. Is there anyway to stop this?

Comment: Can you post a small reproducible example, config and all, that would help us get the same results as you? I can't reproduce it with the details you've given us.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47357/discussion-between-user1089599-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Comment: You can setup a chain of view resolvers.  The one you mention assumes that the return value from your message handling method will be the name of a jsp file.  You can configure a custom view resolver that determines the view based on a `Person` return value.  Or just have a custom view resolver that sends all requests to one view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're just missing `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` from your servlet context configuration. Don't forget to add the namespace declarations and `schemaLocation` values.

Comment: According to http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html it should already be annotated with responsebody no?

Comment: @user1089599 I did not see that. Give me a sec.